# How i add a text in the top menu?

Tags: magento-1.9, menu

Ho can i add a text to my too menu? http://www.benedicto.ro/

I search this question but i did not find something to help me

I want to add a text "free delivery" after "contul meu"

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to edit your links file, by default it does only accept the addlink function. Override the default template by copying it to your own folder, add the text there. You can point it to your own template like this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/template/linkswithtext.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
<default>
```

Then in the loop you could add a condition like:

```
if($_link->getTitle() == "contul meu"){
  echo "thetextiwanttoprint"
}
```

Before `<?php endforeach; ?>`